# catkin: Node is build in wrong place

Tags: catkin, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(netft_rdt_driver)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp diagnostic_updater diagnostic_msgs geometry_msgs roscpp_serialization)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread program_options)

include_directories(include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/netft_rdt_driver.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(netft_node src/netft_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(netft_node ${PROJECT_NAME})
target_link_libraries(netft_node ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(netft_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

catkin_package(
    DEPENDS roscpp diagnostic_updater diagnostic_msgs geometry_msgs
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp diagnostic_updater diagnostic_msgs geometry_msgs
    LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
)
```

The problem is that the executable netft_node does not goes to the usual `devel/lib/pkg_name/.` but to the `build/netft/netft_rdt_driver` and `rosrun` can't find it there. Any idea where is the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74218/catkin:-node-is-build-in-wrong-place/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-08-21**:
Btw you don't have to list the exported dependencies twice - once under DEPENDS and once under CATKIN_DEPENDS. Since all packages listed there are catkin packages you should only list them as CATKIN_DEPENDS and remove DEPENDS completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must invoke catkin_package() *before* adding any targets (libraries and executables). The reason is because catkin_package() will change the location where the targets are built.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2